# How to fix app, that doesnt work after adding assets?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Im trying to do an app, but when i`m trying to add images my application just doesnt work.
in pubspec:

```
  assets:
    - assets/svg/
```

in main:

```
leading: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/svg/btclogo.png',
            height: 15,
            width: 15,
          ),
```

after that, a place for the picture appears, but the picture itself does not appear, and the application does not respond to interactions[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH2dP.png)
[folder of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqWKB.png)

Comment: try `Image.asset`

Comment: Use SvgPicture.asset to display .svg asset files.  And use Image.asset for displaying your .png asset files.